# Add values together and assign them to specific keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

```py
d={}

l = ['a',1,'b',2,'c',3,'a',2,'b',2]
```

How can I convert a list into a dictionary and add the values together if there have the same keys?

```py
d={'a':3,'b':4,'c':3}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: so i have tried to use zip to get it as a dictionary but it does not seem to take the same keys, doesnt return {a:none, b:none, c:none, a:none, b:}

Comment: Please add a new question for the case that they are different lists, as the approach will be different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, convert your list into a list of pairs (and this would work for separate keys and values lists too; `pairs = list(zip(keys, values))` in that case):

```
>>> l = ['a',1,'b',2,'c',3,'a',2,'b',2]
>>> pairs = list(zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('a', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

Then use e.g. [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter()
>>> for key, value in pairs:
...     counter[key] += value
...
>>> counter
Counter({'b': 4, 'a': 3, 'c': 3})
```

If you need just a dict, cast that:

```
>>> dict(counter)
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 3}
```

Alternately, if you don't want to use `Counter`, you can do this with a plain dict:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for key, value in pairs:
...     d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + value
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `Counter`? Obviously you don't need to check if the key is already in the `Counter` object, but are there any other considerations.

Comment: Counters also have other handy methods such as `.most_common()` – and after all, we're counting things here, so using the builtin class that's meant for it sounds like the right fit.

Comment: @Stefan For completeness, I added a dict-only approach.

Comment: thanks, True. I rarely use `collections`. Do you know if using it also gives a performance increase?

Comment: @Stefan Likely yes, since the [`collections` module uses C speedups for some operations](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2165cea548f961b308050f30d1f042a377651d44/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L524-L527).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
d={i:0 for i in set([k for k in l if type(k)==str])}
for i in range(len(l)):
    if type(l[i])==int:
        d[l[i-1]]+=l[i]
```

Output:

```
>>> print(d)
{'c': 3, 'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

The O(n) way:

```
d = {}
l = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'a', 2, 'b', 2]
for k, v in zip(*[iter(l)]*2):
    d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + v
print(d)
```

Result:

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
d={}

l = ['a',1,'b',2,'c',3,'a',2,'b',2]
keys = [l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if i%2==0]
values = [l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if i%2==1]


for i in range(len(keys)):
  if keys[i] in d.keys():
    d[keys[i]] += values[i]
  else:
    d[keys[i]] = values[i]

print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the list and fill the dictionary.

```
l = ['a',1,'b',2,'c',3,'a',2,'b',2]
for e in l:
    # if str(e).isalpha(): ## as in comment: does not support keys like 'a8' or 'hello world'
    if type(e) == str:
        key = e
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = 0
    else:
        print(key, e)
        d[key] += e
        print(d)
d
```

output:

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 3}
```

This also works with lists having a key followed by several values.

Comment: This won't work for keys such as `"a8"` or `"hello world"` though.